# Error code 1603 during Java 1.8 installation on Win 7

Tags: java, installation, error-code

I had Java 1.8_66 on my corporate computer. Today I received a newer version of Java via corporate network (Java 1.8_73).

The installation had broken, therefore I removed my Java version from the computer and tried installing manually. But I can not install any of Java 1.8 versions. I tried many tools to clean up (JavaRA etc), but I always receive error code 1603 during the installation. Even I removed my latest WIN updates also. But nothing has changed. Does anybody have this issue? Earlier versions of Java are not acceptable for me.

I googled and checked many forums. Someones recommends to reinstall the notebook. But I do not want to do it. :-(

Comment: Here is a link from Oracle : https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited on superuser?

Comment: The first thing what I tried was link from Oracle. It had no any sense.

Answer (score 0):

There was no solution for this problem. I found a workaround for it. I installed JDK and JRE to some other computer. Copied the installed files to my comp and setup Path, JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME env. variables. It works as nothing has happened.